# Secure connection between app and server

Tags: ios, https

I would like an iOS app to send data to my web server. For now I issue http get requests like "http://myserver.com?key1=val1&key2=val2" and it works fine

However I would like to secure this a bit so that people don't proxy the requests and send random values to my server.

If I do https, I understand that I generate some private/public keys on the server side, and I have to give those to the app, so that only the app can sign the requests and the server will reject any requests not coming from my app. Is that correct ?

If that's true, is there a way to hide the certificates in the iOS app ? When opening an app on a computer we can see all the files. Could anyone replicate the request with those ?

Thanks

Comment: Anything you can make my phone do via your app, I can do.

Answer (score -2):

On server side you maintain client app unique identifier and one key(pwd) value while installing app and client also maintain that information.Every time client send request with these parameter and server check this parameter with database.

Comment: this doesn't work, someone with a proxy can read those params and replicate the request